# Calling a .bat file from C program fails but if double click it works

Tags: c, batch-file

I have this `file.bat` :

```
cd "C:\Program Files(x86)\Anydesk" && anydesk.exe
```

If i double click on it it works fine and does what i want.

Now i try to launch this bat file inside of my C program :

```
system("path\\file.bat");
```

But it does nothing. I see a super fast cmd opening and nothing else.
I am wondering maybe it is failing because it is calling another application? But i am not sure.

How to make this work?

Comment: Not very knowledgeable about Windows but when you open it manually (ie double clicking) does the UAC pop-up show up? That might be the issue -- the program you're running is (likely) running with user-access while `anydesk.exe` could be requesting admin access (or you might need admin access to run any software under `C:\Program Files(x86)\`, I'm not really sure)

Comment: @WilkMaia UAC doesnt show up when i try to open it manually.
Maybe the second option that you said it's the problem (might need admin access to run any sw under `C:\Program Files(x86)`. 
Let's wait if someone confidently knows the answer, thanks!

Comment: Probably it can't locate your `.bat` file because you specified a relative path that is resolved against the execution path which can be different from what you would expect. Try co use an absolute path.

Comment: @Frankie_C already tried with different paths, it can locate my .bat file

Comment: Does Windows launch CMD for batches, in the first place? You might need to add the prefix "cmd /c ...".

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170) `"cmd /c ..."` is not needed. Try `system("start ...")` ???

Comment: You **don't need** to run the `cmd.exe` to execute the batch. Batch and executables are automatically recognized. Your problem should be that the file can't be located. Open a command window in the location of your executable then run it from the cmd window, so you can read the error from the console window.

Comment: What drive is the batch file running on?  What shows if you if you add a "pause" to the final line of the batch file?  Or run "cmd /k ..." to keep the window open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.bat is not an executable. It is a script which is processed by cmd.com.

So you need to execute it, with your .bat as a parameter:

```
system("cmd /C path\\script.bat");
```

The `/C` key will tell your cmd, to execute the bat and exit, once the bat is finished. You can use `/K` for debug purposes (execute and remain open after completion).

Comment: That's not true. Any executable or batch is automatically recognized.